# What is the best method to queue songs using wavelink library?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm new to this library. I want to make my bot to have a queue option, I already tried declaring an empty list `queue=[]` and use

```python
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, query: str):
    while True:
        tracks = await self.bot.wavelink.get_tracks(f'ytsearch:{query}')
        if not tracks:
            continue
        else:
            break
    player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
    if not player.is_connected:
        await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if player.is_playing:
        if any(f"{channel.id}" in s for s in queue):
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description='Your queue exceed maximum capacity of 1 element',color=0xfd2121))
        else:
            queue.append(f'{channel.id}:{tracks[0]}')
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f"Your song has been queued\n{tracks[0]}",color=0xfd2121))
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'Now playing {tracks[0]} .', color=0xfd2121))
        await player.play(tracks[0])
        while player.is_playing:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if not any(f"{channel.id}" in s for s in queue):
            await player.disconnect()
        else:
            res = [i for i in queue if f'{channel.id}' in i]
            sw=''.join(res)
            while True:
                sw2 = await self.bot.wavelink.get_tracks(f'ytsearch:{sw[19:]}')
                if not sw2:
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
            await player.play(sw2[0])
            queue.remove(f'{channel.id}:{sw[19:]}')
```

but this can only contain 1 queue per channel id and the scripts are way too complicated. I saw some people are using `asyncio.Queue` - some kind of background process - can anybody provide me with an example of using `asyncio.Queue` to queue up songs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of setting up a queue system with `asyncio.Queue()` and `asyncio.Event()`, utilising `wavelink` to handle audio.

```
import wavelink
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
songs = asyncio.Queue()
play_next_song = asyncio.Event()

if not hasattr(client, 'wavelink'):
    client.wavelink = wavelink.Client(bot=client)

async def on_event_hook(event):
    if isinstance(event, (wavelink.TrackEnd, wavelink.TrackException)):
        play_next_song.set()

async def audio_player_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    node = await client.wavelink.initiate_node(host='127.0.0.1',
                                               port=2333,
                                               rest_uri='http://127.0.0.1:2333',
                                               password='PASSWORD',
                                               identifier='TEST',
                                               region='us_central')

    node.set_hook(on_event_hook)

    while True:
        play_next_song.clear()
        song, guild_id = await songs.get()
        player = client.wavelink.get_player(guild_id)
        await player.play(song)
        await play_next_song.wait()

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query: str):
    tracks = await client.wavelink.get_tracks(f'ytsearch:{query}')

    if not tracks:
        return await ctx.send('Could not find any songs with that query.')

    player = client.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
    if not player.is_connected:
        await player.connect(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)

    await ctx.send(f'Added {str(tracks[0])} to the queue.')
    queue_item = (tracks[0], ctx.guild.id)
    await songs.put(queue_item)


client.loop.create_task(audio_player_task())

client.run('token')
```